# How to use a ThrottlingFilter for Jetty in Restlet

Tags: java, jetty, restlet, http-status-code-503

I would like to configure a webservice so that once the accept queue is full the service returns 503. Currently, these requests seem to just time out.

I did set paramters like **maxThreads** and **acceptQueuesize** (as described here: http://www.restlet.org/documentation/1.1/ext/com/noelios/restlet/ext/jetty/JettyServerHelper).

But the service does not respond with 503 once the acceptQueue is full.

It seems jetty's ThrottlingFilter (http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/jetty-6/apidocs/index.html?index-all.html) is what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to apply within my restlet service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to take advantage of ThrottlingFilter unless you deploy your application as a WAR file into Jetty. JettyServerHelper bootstraps Restlet as a standalone server using Jetty to accept HTTP connections and hence cannot utilize a Servlet Filter. I'm not sure if there is anyway to utilize similar processing logic from the ThrottlingFilter in Jetty outside of the Servlet world or not.

Comment: You are right, see this thread on the restlet discuss list: http://restlet.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4447&dsMessageId=1074847